# Python Console Website

Tags: python

I believe that I once saw a website that is like an online Python console. Does anyone know of such a website?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one I know of:

> http://shell.appspot.com/

There's also Lord of the REPL's:

> http://lotrepls.appspot.com/

Python on repl.it:

> http://repl.it/languages/Python

Comment: The appspot example project was the most useful for me, extremely concise and straight forward code.

Answer (score 11):

While not really a "console", [skulpt.org](http://www.skulpt.org/) runs python code client-side with no plugins or anything, which makes it a lot faster than a server-side prompt. For server side and a more traditional shell I found this: http://shell.appspot.com/.

Answer (score 4):

IronPython (using Silverlight or Moonlight 2): http://www.trypython.org/

Comment: The site uses Silverlight (or Moonlight 2) to run IronPython in the browser

Answer (score 4):

This one is very interesting, it has an interactive shell AND a script editing area:

> [Py I/O](http://py-ide-online.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm just find this one http://con.appspot.com/console/

Answer (score 2):

An online python editor: http://doc.pyschools.com/console.